# Smooth fade out fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a smooth refresh on my twitter app,
I'm not good in Javascript, so I can't solve it. I tried like 100 things, but nothing worked...
Could someone solve my problem?

I want when the interval is reached that my object (DIV) fades out and in smooth. But when it fades back in, it must be the new content. When the interval is reached and the content is reloaded, it auto displays the new content now...

Ohw and if someone could fix my second problem, I want that my object (interval object) Is loaded when my page is loaded. My code that I'm using now:

```
    setInterval(function () {
var config1 = {
  "id": '554682452443430912',
  "domId": 'tw-widget1',
  "maxTweets": 1,
  "enableLinks": true,
  "dateFunction": dateFormatter,
};

twitterFetcher.fetch(config1);



function dateFormatter(date) {
  return date.toLocaleString();
}

twitterFetcher.fetch(config1);

}, 10000);
```

Please help me soon.

The HTML "object" is the following:

```
<div id="tw-widget1"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML?  The "`div` object" you're talking about isn't in the code you posted.

Comment: The HTML is just the "domId": 'tw-widget1' in the Javascript. So <div id="tw-widget1"></div> converts into the script above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to chain event handlers together.

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(checkUpdate, 10000);
});

function checkUpdate() {
    var config1 = {
        "id": '554682452443430912',
        "domId": 'tw-widget1',
        "maxTweets": 1,
        "enableLinks": true,
        "dateFunction": dateFormatter,
    };

    // twitterFetcher.fetch(config1);
    var div = $("#" + config1.domId);
    div.data('context', JSON.stringify(config1));
    div.fadeOut(500, updateTweet);
}

function dateFormatter(date) {
     return date.toLocaleString();
}

function updateTweet() {
    var div = $(this); 
    var config1 = jQuery.parseJSON(div.data('context'));

    div.empty();
    div.html("New Tweet ID " + config1.id);
    // Then set it to fadeIn.
    div.fadeIn();
}
```

jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/avjxmqv5/

Code in the $(function () {}) executes when the [DOM is ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) so you could use that to load your object(s).

Give the jsFiddle ten seconds for the action to be visible.

Comment: How can I implimentate it in my javascript code now?

Comment: This works, but I'm onley getting this: 'New Tweet ID 554682452443430912'

Comment: Right, I commented out the twitterFetcher.fetch(config1) line because that's not available on jsFiddle.  You'd also need to change the div.html("New Tweet ID " + config1.id) line to reflect whatever incoming data you have that you want displayed.

Comment: I have now my new code used, but now It doesn't load immediately. So It takes for about 11 seconds (10 seconds for the interval + 1 to load), to load the application... Could you help me? The code I'm using is the following: 

http://jsfiddle.net/8tz6o881/

Comment: Add a manual call to checkUpdate() right before setInterval.  This will cause an immediate update, then set an update for ten seconds later.  I updated the jsFiddle to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been found.
Solution code:

```
    $(function () {
     checkUpdate();
    setInterval(checkUpdate, 30000);
});

function checkUpdate() {
    var config1 = {
        "id": '554682452443430912',
        "domId": 'tw-widget1',
        "maxTweets": 1,
        "enableLinks": true,
        "dateFunction": dateFormatter,
    };

    twitterFetcher.fetch(config1);
    var div = $("#" + config1.domId);
    div.data('context', JSON.stringify(config1));
    div.fadeOut(500, updateTweet);
}

function dateFormatter(date) {
     return date.toLocaleString();
}

function updateTweet() {
    var div = $(this); 
    var config1 = jQuery.parseJSON(div.data('context'));

    //div.empty();
    div.html(twitterFetcher.fetch(config1));
    // Then set it to fadeIn.
    div.fadeIn(500);
}
```

Thanks to all for helping me out!